# getting data from browser indexed db then call api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following useEffect call back function :-

```
import { initDB, useIndexedDB } from "react-indexed-db";
initDB(DBConfig);

const db = useIndexedDB("reads");

    useEffect(() => {
        db.getByIndex("hash", props.match.params.id).then((data) => {
          setToken(data.token);
        });
        handleTextColorSelection(backgroundColor);
        axios
          .post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}khatma/read`, {
            khatma: props.match.params.id,
            part: props.match.params.part,
            section: props.match.params.section,
            token: token,
          })
          .then((res) => {
        
            if (res.data.token) {
              db.add({
                hash: props.match.params.id,
                token: res.data.token,
              }).then(
                (event) => {},
                (error) => {
                  console.log(error);
                }
              );
            }
    })
```

In axios post body i am sending token , if "token" state receive a value stored before in browser indexed db, if there is not object store data found , then a post token will be sent as null.

The problem here, that i noticed that before the  db.getByIndex("hash", ... command get a result, an axios request run, and sending a token as null, even-though later on token state will get a value.

How can i run the db.getByIndex("hash", then if it finish , run axios post request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.then`

```js
const axiosRequest = () => { /* your axios logic */ };

db.getByIndex(...).then(axiosRequest).catch(axiosRequest)
```

Anything you do inside the `then` and `catch` callbacks will be run after the `getByIndex` call

Comment: this issue with this, i also if getByIndex failed want to make axios request, should i write it twice, under the then and under the catch ?

Comment: I want the axios request run in two situation, one if there is not token stored in user browsers db, send request with empty token, if there is token stored , send the stored token

Comment: Yes, you could do the axios request inside a catch block too. I edited my answer to reflect that

Comment: To prevent code duplication of your axios request logic, you can do the code I just edited